# Android SeekBar not draggable under some conditions

Tags: android, seekbar

I have implemented simple SeekBar based slider for volume control (so it should be draggable smoothly). Weird is that with my full code in place, it cannot be dragged - I can only single-click to left or right of the thumb.

Then I remove some code, which has no relation to the SeekBar itself - and it starts working! I am also not using setProgress() at any point, except setting the initial value.

So independently on my code, there is something which prevents from reacting on drag events. Any ideas where to look?

Android 7.0

Comment: Would be helpful if you could post your code related with the seekbard and the code that you say cause the seekbar to work again

Comment: It's not practically possible cause it's distributed around classes. What I have figured out is that I comment out "onProgressChanged()" handler then everything works as expected.

Comment: are you doing much stuff there or stuff that take too much time? cause if you are, you may be blocking the UI thread.

Comment: One guess is that call to Observable.notifyObservers() causing this, currently double-checking this

Comment: you mean https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html ? what are your observers? and what are they doing when they receive the notify?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in my code: SeekBar change listener called notifyObservers(), one of them was the fragment which contained the SeekBar. Worse, Seekbar was a View placed into the RecycleView, so obviously, calling notifyDataSetChanged() somehow canceled all current events.